# How do I assign an adress to a pointer array inside a struct for a BMP structure?

Tags: c, struct

I am currently studying for a C programming exam and stumbled over a problem I am not able to fix.
The structures I will refer to are:

```
typedef struct {
    BYTE blue; 
    BYTE green;     
    BYTE red;
} tRgb; 

typedef struct {
    tFileHeader *pFile;
    tInfoHeader *pInfo;
    tRgb **pixel;
    char *data; // pointer for dynamical allocation 
} tBmp;
```

The assignment points out that I have to allocate the pointer array (`tRgb **pixel;`) dynamically and point to the address of the first `tRgb` struct which is `bmp + 55`, hence the File and InfoHeader fill 55 bytes:

```
tBmp *createBmp(int width, int height)
{
    int added;
    int error = 0;

    size_t totalSize = sizeof(tFileHeader) +
                       sizeof(tInfoHeader) +
                       height * width * sizeof(tRgb);

    size_t InfoAndFileHeader = sizeof(tFileHeader) +
                               sizeof(tInfoHeader);

    added = 0;
    if (width % 4 != 0)
    {
        added = width % 4; // since one row should be at least 4Bytes for compiling purposes
        totalSize += (added * height) * sizeof(char);
    }

    tBmp* bmp;
    bmp = NULL;
    bmp = malloc(sizeof(tBmp));
    if (bmp != NULL)
    {
        bmp->pFile = bmp->data = NULL;
        bmp->pFile = bmp->data = malloc(totalSize);
        if (bmp->pFile == NULL) error = -1;

        bmp->pInfo = bmp->data + sizeof(tFileHeader);

        tRgb** pixel = malloc(height * sizeof(tRgb *)); //pixel[i] represents a row
        if (pixel == 0) error = -2;
        if (!error)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                pixel[i] = bmp->data + sizeof(InfoAndFileHeader + i * (width + added));
            }
        }
        bmp->pixel = pixel;

        free(pixel);
        free(bmp->pFile);
        free(bmp);
```

Thanks for reading, and feel free to leave a comment if you got any suggestions to the code in terms of structure or sth:)

Comment: I would start from proper formating **before** posting the question. Do you really think that we will analyze something like this>

Comment: I am sorry it had been that horrendously formatted. I used this editor for the first time and the backspaces just appeared, so I assumed it had been casted by the editor

Comment: Don't do (e.g.) `((*bmp).pixel)[0]` Much more idiomatic is: `bmp->pixel[0]`

Comment: Note that you don't want: `tRgb** pixel;` Instead, you want: `tRgb *pixel;` As you have it, you'd need a separate `malloc` for each pixel.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You've got a bit too much indirection. You can simplify things a bit with: `typedef struct { tFileHeader File; tInfoHeader Info; tRgb *pixel; } tBmp;` Then, do: `tBmp *bmp = malloc(sizeof(*bmp)); bmp->pixel = malloc(sizeof(tRgb) * width * height);`

Comment: yes, that's true but I need an array of pointers. According to the task I got 3 rgb *  pointing to the memory of bmp+45, +49, and +53. This rgb* should also be dynamically allocated and pointed by rgb **
Moreover, I don't like this big allocation either but the assignment says that it has to be stored as one chunk of memory. :(
isnt it possible to write the n-th elemnt of the pointer inside the stuct?

Comment: Your description is very unclear. It is hard to say anything without having a look at the unedited assignment.

Comment: I´ve added a picture that contains all the pointers and where they are supposed to point at. Additionally you see which elements are suppose to be dynamic in german "dynamisch" 
Zeigervektor translates to pointer array. So I got 1 pointer for each column and the chars are for compiling puposes. (Ive deactivated line assignment)

Comment: thanks @CraigEstey for showing me what I did wrong with the width and height! I read the example and had a wrong thought

Comment: The error is: `sizeof(InfoAndFileHeader + i * (width + added))` -> `sizeof(InfoAndFileHeader) + i * (width + added)`

Comment: You are not supposed to keep fixing the code in the question. It makes the comments and answers inconsistent.  Reformatting the code is OK as long as it does not introduce semantic differences. The original post definitely needed some cleanup, but the incremental changes to get to a *(solved)* stage are not OK on Stack Overflow.

Comment: so shall I keep the code as it was originally or add some things as recommended @chqrlie?

Comment: @arslansuns: at this point, I am just going to rollback to my latest edit and remove the `(solved)`.  This is your first question, no hard feelings... just keep in mind for future posts.

Comment: @chqrlie I sure will, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `added` is computed incorrectly and used incorrectly: you should compute the `rowsize` by rounding `with * sizeof(tRgb)` to the next multiple of `4` and use that to compute the bitmap size and the row pointers.
- the expression `sizeof(InfoAndFileHeader + i * (width + added))` is incorrect. `InfoAndFileHeader` is a size, not a structure and the parentheses are misplaced anyway. It should have been:

  ```
  InfoAndFileHeader + i * (width + added)
  ```
- the loop to initialize the row pointer should iterate on `height`, not `width`.

Here is a modified version:

```
tBmp *createBmp(int width, int height) {
    // align rowsize on the next multiple of 4 bytes
    size_t rowsize = (width * sizeof(tRgb) + 3) & ~3;
    size_t InfoAndFileHeader = sizeof(tFileHeader) + sizeof(tInfoHeader);
    size_t totalSize = InfoAndFileHeader + height * rowsize;

    // allocate the structure, row pointer array and bitmap data
    tBmp *bmp = malloc(sizeof(*bmp));
    char *data = calloc(totalSize, 0);  // initialize the bitmap to black.
    tRgb **pixel = malloc(sizeof(*pixel) * height);

    // if any of the allocations failed, free everything and bail out
    if (bmp == NULL || data == NULL || pixel == NULL) {
        free(pixel);
        free(data);
        free(bmp);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        // initialize the row pointers
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            pixel[i] = (tRgb *)(data + InfoAndFileHeader + i * rowsize);
        }
        // initialize the structure members
        bmp->pFile = (tFileHeader *)data;
        bmp->pInfo = (tInfoHeader *)(data + sizeof(tFileHeader));
        bmp->pixel = pixel;
        bmp->data = data;
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Be aware that `tFileHeader` and `tInfoHeader` must be defined as **packed** structures as they are not properly aligned in the BMP file format.  It is usually not a good idea to try and map file formats directly in memory as alignment requirements and byte ordering may vary from one architecture to another.  The pixel array is portable, but the headers should be read from and written to disk using functions that handle the necessary conversions.

Comment: this code is godlike! I tried more and found the same bugs but didn't come up with such a straightforward approach! However, I don't really understand how you compute "rawsize". Would you mind explaining this line?

Lastly, is this cast from char*  mandatory or additional?

Comment: @arslansuns: `rowsize` is compute as the length of the row (`width * 3`) rounded up to the next multiple of `4`.  This can be done with bit masking as posted or with `size_t rowsize = (width * sizeof(tRgb) + 3) / 4 * 4`, which is less readable.

Comment: @arslansuns:  The casts for the `pFile` and `pInfo` assignments are recommended and indeed necessary if you compile with an increased warning level such as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, which will help find silly bugs very effectively.